# Socket IO invalid frame with express server

Tags: javascript, socket.io

```
socket.io.js:1706 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=2k8bdvHbYeNxHgbnAAAA' failed: Invalid frame header
```

Always see this error with my Javascript express server.
Anyone know what it is about ?

Though it doesn't block my code, sometimes it cannot reconnect.
Save my life please.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same version of socket.io and socket. io-client on both server and client.
The problem might be you are using different versions also you might be initializing the server with socket.io twice.

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem. It's because I use PeerJs and Socket.IO.
When I comment out PeerJs, this error gone. But I have to use both of them. Do you have any experience of doing this?